# Ejecutar archivos .sql en php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo una base de datos en mysql, la cosa es que cada vez que introduzco datos nuevos necesito ejecutar una serie de funciones y prodecimientos situadas en diferentes archivos.sql, Por tanto necesito una forma de ejecutar el "source archivo.sql" desde php.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola alvaro9912, no logro entenderte del todo. "source archivo.sql" es un script y necesitas lanzarlo desde PHP?

Comment: procedimientos almacenados no seria mejor?

Comment: Buenas Srsole, resulta que los procedimientos los almaceno en un archivo.sql y los ejecuto con una terminal específica de mysql que se instala en windows. Por tanto quiero crear un archivo capaz de ejecutar todos los archivos .sql para no ir ejecutandolos 1 a 1 cada vez que inserto datos en la BDD

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es ejecutar un script **.sql** desde PHP, puedes utilizar los comandos [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shell-exec.php) o [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.exec.php), que te permiten ejecutar cualquier comando del shell desde PHP. Sea como sea, te recomiendo que utilices **exec()**, ya que te permite conocer el código de salida del comando ejecutado.

```php
$cmd = "mysql -uyour_user_name -pyour_password database_name < script.sql" ;
exec($cmd, $salida, $codigo) ;
```